# How to count duplicates value in a list in reference to order

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I having problem with counting duplicate values in list.
I having this list **[1 2 7 2 3 3 4 4 5 ]** and want to count the duplicate value inside in reference to their order and get this output 
**[0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]**.

another example: **[ 4 5 2 2 2 7 9 9 9 ] -> [ 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 ]**

someone help me implement this in java?
i already tried using Collections.**frequency(list, list.get(i))** but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Java 7 solution which should work for you.  It reuses the input `List` to store the frequencies.  There is probably a 2-3 liner solution in Java 8.

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 7, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5);
Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (int i=0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
    int val = input.get(i);
    Integer count = (counts.get(val) == null) ? 0 : counts.get(val) + 1;
    input.set(i, count);
    counts.put(val, count);
}

System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I also tested the code with your other example and it worked:

```
[4 5 2 2 2 7 9 9 9] -> [0 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Really helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to count number of times a number appears in that list. For this you have to create a hashmap. Then iterate over your list and store the numbers into the hashmap while counting the number of times it appears. You have to store the number as key and number of times it appeard as its value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in Python :
(`a` is your list)

```
print map(lambda x:sum([1 for i in a[:x[0]] if i==x[1]]) , enumerate(a))
```

Demo :

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 7, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> print map(lambda x:sum([1 for i in a[:x[0]] if i==x[1]]) , enumerate(a))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: It was a generic question initially, later the OP added the condition.